# Sharepoint 2013 setting time zone from UTC to Local Time in workflow email

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I am very much a SharePoint "newbie"--the end user version, not the farm manager version. That means I need the simplest answer possible to my question, please!

I am working on a time off (approval) workflow. I would like to send an email with the task notification of the manager, but within the email, I want to send the dates and times for which a person is requesting leave.

Unfortuantely, all I can get returned in the email is Zulu (UTC) time! Although UTC makes computers happy, it doesn't make my users happy. They want to see the time returned in local time.

How can I do that? Here's the copy of what I'm working on doing. I want the start and end times to return in local times, NOT Zulu time.

```
    You have a new task.

    [%Task: Title%] 

    Assigned To [%Task: Assignee%] 
    Due Date [%Task: Due Date%] 
    Description [%Task: Description%] 
        Related Item [%Task: Related Item Title%] 

    [%Current Item:Created By%] is requesting time off.

    [%Current Item:Event Category%]

    Start: [%Current Item:Start Time%], [%Current Item:Start Time%]

    End: [%Current Item:End Time%], [%Current Item:End Time%]
```